# Generate Heat-map with lat-lng in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-visualization, heatmap

I am using angularjs with mongodb.

I have table which contains user coordinates.

```
{ "mac" : "aa:22:01:d2:e6:f9","lat" : 33.53625,"lng" : -111.92674, "time" : 2017-07-12T04:44:13.707Z}
{ "mac" : "aa:22:01:d2:e6:f9","lat" : 33.53625,"lng" : -111.92674, "time" : 2017-07-12 04:44:13.707Z}
{ "mac" : "aa:22:01:d2:e6:f9","lat" : 33.53625,"lng" : -111.92674, "time" : 2017-07-12 04:46:59.707Z}
{ "mac" : "aa:22:01:d2:e6:f9","lat" : 33.53625,"lng" : -111.92674, "time" : 2017-07-12 04:47:29.707Z}
```

I want to display heat map. can anyone point me the best way to achieve this.

I'll have building image which i need to adjust in background later.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to map your data to an array of `google.maps.LatLng` objects. Then init the map, init heatmap layer with mapped data and assign heatmap layer to the map. Check the [**sample**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer)

You need also to include the [**visualization**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/visualization) library, because `HeatmapLayer` is there.

```js
function initMap() {

  /* Data points defined as an array of LatLng objects */
  var data = [{
    "mac": "aa:22:01:d2:e6:f9",
    "lat": 33.53625,
    "lng": -111.92674,
    "time": '2017-07-12T04:44:13.707Z'
  }, {
    "mac": "aa:22:01:d2:e6:f9",
    "lat": 33.53625,
    "lng": -111.92674,
    "time": '2017-07-12 04:44:13.707Z'
  }, {
    "mac": "aa:22:01:d2:e6:f9",
    "lat": 33.53625,
    "lng": -111.92674,
    "time": '2017-07-12 04:46:59.707Z'
  }, {
    "mac": "aa:22:01:d2:e6:f9",
    "lat": 33.53625,
    "lng": -111.92674,
    "time": '2017-07-12 04:47:29.707Z'
  }];

  var heatmapData = data.map(function(item) {
    return new google.maps.LatLng(item.lat, item.lng)
  });

  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(33.53625, -111.92674);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: center,
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'satellite'
  });

  var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: heatmapData
  });
  heatmap.setMap(map);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{
  display:none !important;
}
```

```html
<script async defer type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap"></script>

<div id="map" style="width:500px;height:150px"></div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to set custom background image over map? Also how to set map center according to coordinates. so all coordinates can be shown in area.

Comment: _Is there any way to set custom background image over map?_ - this is another question but I'm sure that this is possible - just go to search on the web for this question. _Also how to set map center according to coordinates. so all coordinates can be shown in area_ - since you have all the data you can calculate the latitude and longitude and then instantiate the central point `var center = new google.maps.LatLng(calcedLat, calcedLng);`